# How can I print n days old date?

Tags: shell, osx, date, variable

For 2 days old date I usually do this

`echo $(date -v -2d)`

What i am looking to do is something like this

```
n=5
echo $(date -v -nd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself

```
n=5
echo $(date -v -${n}d)
```

Comment: Why the `echo`? `date -v "-${n}d"` should be enough.

Comment: sure point noted, but why quotes? it works without it as well.

Comment: See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) Leaving it unquoted introduces an unnecessary dependency of that code on the `$IFS` variable in shells like sh/bash

Comment: BTW, don't be put off by downvoters. You did the right thing to post  an answer to your own question after you found it yourself. Note that it's perfectly fine to edit your posts to merge in suggestions given in comments by others. What matters is that in the end we have the most helpful Q's & A's as possible.